# How can I observe data-attributes of ZK elements?

Tags: java, events, addeventlistener, zk

I want to execute something in backend, when the data-attribute of a ZK element changes.
There's a `MutationObserver` in Javascript, is there something similar in ZK that I can use?

I already checked the ZK `Events` class but there doesn't seem to be an event that listens to attribute changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event listener or similar by default that would be triggered when changing a clientAttribute on a component.

Where does the change originate from? Is it an event happening at client-side? Or a change done on the component object in Java? Could you explain the use case? there might be a different way to achieve it :)

Edit: technical solution after exchanges.
firing an event from client to server side:
https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Communication/AU_Requests/Client-side_Firing#Fire_Event_Directly_to_Server

I'd recommend firing a `"onCustom"` event instead (any event name starting by `"on"+yourEventName` ). You will also need to use `toServer:true` in the event optional arguments to have it fired to the server directly. this one is a good option: `zAu.send(new zk.Event(wgt, "onFoo", {foo: 'my data'}, {toServer:true}));` where `wgt` is the widget object, `"onFoo"` is the custom event name, `{foo: 'my data'}` is the payload, if you need to send anything back to the server, and `{toServer: true}` is the optional arguments, with the toServer entry

the issue with firing `onChange` is that is is a default event sent by default actions. there is already behaviors tied to `onChange` on most components. you might trigger a default workflow which expects a specific payload and create an error situation. By sending a `onCustomName` (whathever it is, just not a default event) event, you are sure to only trigger the listener in by invoking the `zAu.send`

Comment: the data-attribute I want to observe is changed by JS on the client side

Comment: In that case, since you can observe it at client-side already, I would just sent a custom event to the server when the change happen.
https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Communication/AU_Requests/Client-side_Firing#Fire_Event_Directly_to_Server

Comment: I could make a fiddle if that's not clear, let me know

Comment: I already tried `zk.Widget.$($(this).prop("id")).fire("onChange");` and set up an `onChange`-listener in backend but the listener does not recognize the event fired

Comment: I'd recommend firing a "onCustom" event instead (any event name starting by "on"+yourEventName.
You will also need to use toServer:true in the event optional arguments to have it fired to the server directly.
this one is a good option:
`zAu.send(new zk.Event(wgt, "onFoo", {foo: 'my data'}, {toServer:true}));`
where wgt is the widget object, "onFoo" is the custom event name, {foo: 'my data'} is the payload, if you need to send anything back to the server, and {toServer: true} is the optional arguments, with the toServer entry

Comment: the issue with firing `onChange` is that there is already behaviors tied to onChange on most components. you might trigger a default workflow which expects a specific payload and create an error situation. By sending a `onCustomName` (whathever it is, just not a default event) event, you are sure to only trigger the listener in by invoking the zAu.send

Comment: Another note on that, the event listener must be on the Component matching the widget passed as first argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working! Can you add the code from your comment to your answer so others can find the solution easier?